# application and its database lifecycle hosted on cloud (UEC)

Tags: database, saas, cloud-hosting, eucalyptus

A trivial but crucial concept that I am not able to understand in cloud-architecture.

We have installed an web-app in an kvm-image and that image has been registered with Eucalyptus cloud.

Now, if multiple customers instantiate the same image, how will their individual data will be persisted in the database?  Will I have to re-architect the database to support multi-tenancy?

But what we wanted is "quick-saas-enablement" using virtualisation without re-architecturing existing application and its database.

Please guide us :)

Comment: Some extra reference from Sun http://arstechnica.com/software/news/2008/04/sun-to-help-companies-saasify-apps-with-virtualization.ars

Answer (score 1):

Images (what you upload and register to be run as instances later on) are, if you will, read-only. Once a user execute euca-run-instances, a copy of that image will be copy and assembled for that specific instance. So every time a user (who has access to the image) run an instance, it will get *exactly* what has been uploaded originally. All the modification will be lost once the instance terminates.

In short, you don't want to upload password, or dynamic information into an image. For dynamic information you can use EBS (elastic block storage). You can also customize instances using *user-data* (for script examples search cloud-init or look at the [Eucalyptus Recipes project](https://projects.eucalyptus.com/redmine/projects/recipes)).

Some people would use boot from EBS (instances that persists across stopping and rebooting), while others uses ephemeral instances coupled with EBS volumes (some of the above scripts), or aggressive replication (Netflix for example). Almost all use Walrus/S3 for backup and disaster recovery.